# Поиск значения в массиве с заменой

Tags: php

Есть переменная $r, которую я преобразовал в массив.

```
$a = 2;
$b = 3;

$r = "01.0":"0", "02.0":"0", "03.0":"0", "04.0":"0"
$arr_r = explode(',',$r);
```

Как в массиве найти элемент равный $a - то есть у которого до двоеточия в первых кавычках (должен найти "02.0":"0" ), и в случае если есть такой, заменить ему значение после двоеточия на $b? (Если нет, добавить ест-но, но это я и сам напишу).

```
$r = "01.0":"0", "02.0":"0", "03.0":"0", "04.0":"0"        // из этого
$r = "01.0":"0", "02.0":"3", "03.0":"0", "04.0":"0"        // в это
```

Comment: А этот код у Вас работоспособен?

Comment: по моему это словарь из python, ну у ТС синтаксис похож на питонский словарь :) lol

Comment: это работоспособная часть кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ничего не понятно, но попробую помочь, это вам не python

```
$a = "01.0:0"
$r = "01.0:0,02.0:0,03.0:0,04.0:0";
$exp = explode(",", $r);
if(in_array($a,$exp) // если есть значение а в массиве exp
  // заменяем и делаем то что там нужно
```

Comment: Ващщщее. Это супер сложно, а так додуматься до этого только гений PHP может =)) 

Раз уж вы "массив" представили так:

      $r = "01.0:0,02.0:0,03.0:0,04.0:0";

то не легче уж было бы юзать strstr( или mb_strpos ), приняв $r за строку ?

Comment: как ТС попросил я сделал, а такие вещи как mb_strpos ему ещё рано, за ним пойдет ещё один вопрос от ТС-са :))

Comment: mb_strpos рано? Тогда explode - подавно)))

Answer (score 0):

Это пипец.

> есть переменная $r, которую я
> преобразовал в масиив.

и как, расскажи ты её преобразовал в массив? И как она изначально выглядела?

```
$a = 2;
$b = 3;

$r = "01.0":"0", "02.0":"0", "03.0":"0", "04.0":"0"
$arr_r = explode(',',$r);
```

Как массивы объявлять знаем? как строки объявлять знаем?

массив

```
$r = array(0=>"01.0:0",1=>"02.0:0",2=>"03.0:0",3=>"04.0:0");// допустим
```

Строка

```
 $r = "01.0:0,02.0:0,03.0:0,04.0:0"; // допустим
```

**Массив перебирается циклом можно готовой функцией в PHP
Строку можно и EXPLODE()**

у меня все. писать дальше не хочу. Вопрос вообще задан не то чтобы неправильно, а еще и с такими ошибками.

Comment: чего ты накинулся, сам таким не был? или ты родился со словами: **P**ersonal **H**ome **P**age!

Comment: Ну уж простите, но путать строки и массивы это пипец.

Нет я не был таким, у меня были ошибки типов а не глупые вопросы почему, массив, который на самом деле строка и т.д. и т.п.